# StartWith method for arrays

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

Is there a StartWith method for arrays in .NET? Or something similar to it in LINQ?

```
var arr1 = { "A", "B, "C" }
var arr2 = { "A", "B, "C", "D" } 

var arr3 = { "A", "B, "CD" } 
var arr4 = { "E", "A, "B", "C" } 

arr2.StartWith(arr1) // true
arr1.StartWith(arr2) // false

arr3.StartWith(arr1) // false
arr4.StartWith(arr1) // false
```

Or I should do it straightforward:

```
bool StartWith(string[] arr1, string[] arr2)
{
     if (arr1.Count() < arr2.Count) return false;

     for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Count(), i++)
     {
        if (arr2[i] != arr1[i]) return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: Do it "straightforward". There´s no built-in way of doing this. Btw.: questions about working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: avoid using `.Count()` use `.Length`

Comment: Don't assume that all sequences are arrays. It's the current year. Use `IEnumerable<T>`. Call GetEnumerator() on both parameters and loop on those.

Comment: @DanielA.White not necessarily. Count() checks wheter source implements `IList` and if yes - uses `Count` property..

Comment: [Edit] Nevermind, looks like you want to match all elements and not just a true "starts with".

Comment: @RyanIntravia Vlad is looking to see if a sequence of elements in an array is at the start of another array

Comment: @RyanIntravia No, OP wants to check if arr2´s first n elements are those from arr1, not just the very first.

Comment: When you want efficient don't use LINQ or linq tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool answer = arr2.Take(arr1.Length).SequenceEqual(arr1);
```

Comment: I'd think you'd also need to make sure `arr2.Length >= arr1.Length` since a shorter array cannot start with a longer one.

Comment: No need: If `arr2` is shorter than `arr1`, then `arr2.Take(arr1.Length)` will return the entire `arr2`, and `.SequenceEqual(arr1)` will correctly return false.

Answer (score 6):

Your "striaghtformward" way is the way most LINQ methods would be doing it anyway. There are a few tweaks you could do. For example make it a extension method and use a comparer for the comparison of the two types so custom comparers could be used.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static bool StartWith<T>(this T[] arr1, T[] arr2)
    {
        return StartWith(arr1, arr2, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    static bool StartWith<T>(this T[] arr1, T[] arr2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
         if (arr1.Length < arr2.Length) return false;

         for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Length, i++)
         {
            if (!comparer.Equals(arr2[i], arr1[i])) return false;
         }

         return true;
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE: For fun I decided to take the time and write a little more "advanced" version that would work with any `IEnumerable<T>` and not just arrays.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static bool StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, IEnumerable<T> @startsWith)
    {
        return StartsWith(@this, startsWith, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    static bool StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, IEnumerable<T> startsWith, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("this");
        if (startsWith == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("startsWith");
        if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");

        //Check to see if both types implement ICollection<T> to get a free Count check.
        var thisCollection = @this as ICollection<T>;
        var startsWithCollection = startsWith as ICollection<T>;
        if (thisCollection != null && startsWithCollection != null && (thisCollection.Count < startsWithCollection.Count)) 
            return false;

        using (var thisEnumerator = @this.GetEnumerator())
        using (var startsWithEnumerator = startsWith.GetEnumerator())
        {
            //Keep looping till the startsWithEnumerator runs out of items.
            while (startsWithEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                //Check to see if the thisEnumerator ran out of items.
                if (!thisEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    return false;

                if (!comparer.Equals(thisEnumerator.Current, startsWithEnumerator.Current))
                    return false;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
var result = arr2.Take(arr1.Length).SequenceEqual(arr1);
```

To optimize it further you can add the check  `arr2.Length >= arr1.Length` in the start like:

```
var result = arr2.Length >= arr1.Length && arr2.Take(arr1.Length).SequenceEqual(arr1);
```

The end result would be same.

Comment: This is missing the check to make sure `arr1` is not longer than `arr2`

Answer (score 3):

Try Enumerable.SequenceEqual(a1, a2) but trim your first array, i.e.,

```
 var arr1 = { "A", "B, "C" }
 var arr2 = { "A", "B, "C", "D" }

 if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(arr1, arr2.Take(arr1.Length))
```

Comment: Or use it as extension-method as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to require everything to be an array, and you don't want to call `Count()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` that may be a large query, when you only really want to sniff at the first four items or whatever.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var a = new[] { "a", "b" };
        var b = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        var c = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        var d = new[] { "x", "y" };

        Console.WriteLine("b.StartsWith(a): {0}", b.StartsWith(a));
        Console.WriteLine("b.StartsWith(c): {0}", b.StartsWith(c));
        Console.WriteLine("b.StartsWith(d, x => x.Length): {0}", 
                          b.StartsWith(d, x => x.Length));
    }

    public static bool StartsWith<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
        IEnumerable<T> prefixCandidate, 
        Func<T, T, bool> compare = null)
    {
        using (var eseq = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        using (var eprefix = prefixCandidate.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if (compare == null)
            {
                compare = (x, y) => Object.Equals(x, y);
            }

            eseq.MoveNext();
            eprefix.MoveNext();

            do
            {
                if (!compare(eseq.Current, eprefix.Current))
                    return false;

                if (!eprefix.MoveNext())
                    return true;
            }
            while (eseq.MoveNext());

            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool StartsWith<T, TProperty>(
        this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
        IEnumerable<T> prefixCandidate,
        Func<T, TProperty> selector)
    {
        using (var eseq = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        using (var eprefix = prefixCandidate.GetEnumerator())
        {
            eseq.MoveNext();
            eprefix.MoveNext();

            do
            {
                if (!Object.Equals(
                        selector(eseq.Current),
                        selector(eprefix.Current)))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (!eprefix.MoveNext())
                    return true;
            }
            while (eseq.MoveNext());

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some different ways of doing that. I didn't optimize or fully validated everything, there is room for improvement everywhere. But this should give you some idea.

The best performance will always be going low level, if you grab the iterator and go step by step you can get much faster results.

Methods and performance results:

```
StartsWith1   00:00:01.9014586
StartsWith2   00:00:02.1227468
StartsWith3   00:00:03.2222109
StartsWith4   00:00:05.5544177
```

Test method:

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    bool test = action(arr2, arr1);
}
watch.Stop();
return watch.Elapsed;
```

Methods:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtender
{
    public static bool StartsWith1<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> compare)
    {
        if (source.Count() < compare.Count())
        {
            return false;
        }

        using (var se = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            using (var ce = compare.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (ce.MoveNext() && se.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (!ce.Current.Equals(se.Current))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool StartsWith2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> compare) =>
        compare.Take(source.Count()).SequenceEqual(source);

    public static bool StartsWith3<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> compare)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (compare == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(compare));
        }

        if (source.Count() < compare.Count())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return compare.SequenceEqual(source.Take(compare.Count()));
    }

    public static bool StartsWith4<T>(this IEnumerable<T> arr1, IEnumerable<T> arr2)
    {
        return StartsWith4(arr1, arr2, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }
    public static bool StartsWith4<T>(this IEnumerable<T> arr1, IEnumerable<T> arr2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (arr1.Count() < arr2.Count()) return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!comparer.Equals(arr2.ElementAt(i), arr1.ElementAt(i))) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can improve StartsWith1 with a few tweaks. Look at [the updated part of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40163518/80274), it is pretty much the same as StartsWith1 except I add a cast to `ICollection<T>` to do the length check and if I can't I just watch for `arr1`'s enumerator to run out of items before `arr2`. doing that removes a extra enumeration of the list if the list did not implement `ICollection<T>` internally saving you potentially quite a few cycles for large lists or lists backed by `yeild return` methods.

Comment: Every time You call Count() on IEnumerable You are enumerating through all elements if it is not internally just array but for example some linq query. ElementAt is simmilar. In StartsWith4 You made basically foreach loop, but with O(n^2) time complexity, that is terrible. Please do not treat IEnumerable as array, enumerate it only once.